# Dagger missing binding while adding AndroidInjector

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have the following problem: I started to study Dagger 2 and trying to add injections to my App class. Here's the code of my App class:

```
class TraktTvApp : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: AndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity>? = androidInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appContext = applicationContext
        instance = this

        initStetho()
        initFabric()

        DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this)

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
                .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->

                    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                        return@OnCompleteListener
                    }

                    val token = task.result?.token
                }
                )
    }

    private fun initFabric() {
        Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics(), CrashlyticsNdk())
    }

    private fun initStetho() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: TraktTvApp
        lateinit var appContext: Context
    }

}
```

In this class I have `appContext` as Property and I am trying to replace it with injection. For this purpose I added this lines

DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)

When I build my App everything was ok, but when I added

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var androidInjector: AndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity>? = androidInjector
```

And tried to build I got this error:

```
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector<android.app.Activity> is injected at
          com.mikhailovskii.trakttv.TraktTvApp.androidInjector
      com.mikhailovskii.trakttv.TraktTvApp is injected at
          com.mikhailovskii.trakttv.di.AppComponent.inject(com.mikhailovskii.trakttv.TraktTvApp)
```

I have already seen possible solutions, but none of them helped me. Here's the code of my `AppModule`:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(application: TraktTvApp): Context {
        return application.applicationContext
    }

}
```

And here's `AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [
            AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
            AppModule::class
        ]
)
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance

        fun application(application: TraktTvApp): Builder

        fun build():AppComponent

    }

    fun inject(application: TraktTvApp)

}
```

So, what's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Why would you ever want to add `AndroidInjector` in you Application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to add `AndroidInjector` manually. You can use Dagger base classes so Dagger will handle it for you

You should extend your `Application` class from `DaggerApplication`

```
 class MyApp: DaggerApplication() {

    /**
     * Returns the injector
     */
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {

        val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
        appComponent.inject(this)

        return appComponent

    }
```

Also your `Main Component` extends `AndroidInjector`

```
/**
 * The main component that holds and services all modules within its builder.
 */
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApp> {

    /**
     * A {@see [Component.Builder]} that initializes necessary implementations
     */
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application : Application) : Builder
        fun build() : AppComponent
    }

}
```

If you want to use Context, you can add it your AppModule

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
        return application.applicationContext
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, but can you explain me also what way should I get the context now? Before I did in in the following way: `TraktTvApp.appContext` and now I should do it in what way? I tried this:             `AppModule().provideContext(TraktTvApp())`, but I don't think this is the right way

Comment: Or I should change it in App class, like `appContext = AppModule().provideContext(this)`